# Python/Django - How to submit a form, within a form, through a modal?

Tags: python, django

### *Scenario*

I have two forms. In my case, I want to submit a second form through a modal, while being in the first form template. Instead of this, modal pops up as it should be when I click the link, but when I hit the submit button, the modal form is not submitted, but the main form is. I created a minimized project that simulates the problem.

### *Code*

```
# models.py
class TestModel1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class TestModel2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


# forms.py
class TestModel1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel1
        fields = ["name", ]


class TestModel2Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel2
        fields = ["name", ]

# views.py
class TestModel1Create(CreateView):
    model = TestModel1
    form_class = TestModel1Form
    template_name = 'mytestapp/testmodel1_form.html'
    success_url = '/testmodel1/create'

class TestModel2Create(CreateView):
    model = TestModel2
    form_class = TestModel2Form
    template_name = 'mytestapp/testmodel2_form.html'
    success_url = '/testmodel1/create'
```

Here is the "main" form, testmodel1_form.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <a href="/testmodel2/create/" class='li-modal'>Goto form 2</a>
    <div id="theModal" class="modal fade text-center">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('.li-modal').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#theModal').modal('show').find('.modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    </script>

    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the modal form, testmodel2_form.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### *What I look for*

The way I want this to work, is while being in the main form, POST the secondary form through the modal, and then get the main form reloaded.